# Typescript error coming after using the spread operator on a state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I don't know if the interface syntax is wrong code editor is happy though

```
interface innerQuiz1 {
  question: string;
  sectionId: number;
  attachmentId: number;
  options: string[];
  answers: string[];
}

interface innerQuiz {
  attempts: string;
  passing: string;
  quiz: innerQuiz1[];
  quizTitle: string;
}

interface courseQuiz {
  quiz: innerQuiz[];
  passing: number;
  attempts: number;
  quizTitle: string;
}
```

structure of the quiz is like this[image: console outpput]
`const [courseQuiz, setCourseQuiz] = useState<courseQuiz>();`

```
  const onQuizFormSubmit = (e) => {
    console.log("from", e);
    setCourseQuiz({
      ...e,
      quiz: e.quiz.map((item, i) => ({
        sectionId: i,
        attachmentId: null,
        question: item.question,
        options: item.answer.map((item) => item.option),
        answers: item.answer
          .filter((item) => item.checked === true)
          .map((item) => item.option),
      })),
    });
  };
```

This function is updating the state without any error

```
  const courseQuizCheck = () => {
    console.log("From course quiz check", courseQuiz);
    if (courseQuiz) return courseQuiz;
    else {
      return {
        quiz: [],
        passing: null,
        attempts: null,
        quizTitle: null,
      };
    }
  };
```

Again inside a function, I am trying to  spread the course quiz like this

```
  const getCourseFromForm = () => {
    console.log("1.from getCourseFromForm", courseQuiz);
    console.log(
      "2.from getCourseFromForm after running the coursequizCheck function",
      courseQuizCheck()
    );

    console.log("4.coursequiz is spreded", ...courseQuiz);
    console.log(
      "3.from getCourseFromForm after spreading the coursequizCheckfunction",
      ...courseQuizCheck()
    );
    }
```

Typescript is complaining about **...courseQuiz** inside 3rd console log and the error is

**const courseQuiz: courseQuiz | undefined
Type 'courseQuiz | undefined' is not an array type.ts(2461)**

Typescript is complaining about **...courseQuizCheck()** inside 4th console log and the error is

**

```
const courseQuizCheck: () => courseQuiz | {
    quiz: never[];
    passing: null;
    attempts: null;
    quizTitle: null;
}
```

Type 'courseQuiz | { quiz: never[]; passing: null; attempts: null; quizTitle: null; }' is not an array type.ts(2461)
**
The console is also showing an error and the error is
**
TypeError: courseQuiz is not iterable
**

Comment: You are attempting to spread an object into a function call which isn't going to work and the error message seems pretty clear to me. It's unclear why you'd even *want* to use spread in your call to `console.log` since it handles objects and arrays just fine. If this is homework for a course (i.e. you have to use spread because that's part of the assignment) your instructor or classmates might be better resources since they're more likely to understand what the instructor wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to spread the variable courseQuiz of interface CourseQuiz which looks like this :

```
interface courseQuiz {
  quiz: innerQuiz[];
  passing: number;
  attempts: number;
  quizTitle: string;
}
```

**You cannot spread objects inside the console log function, only arrays.**